# Expo-Image-Picker does not open Camera or Image Library on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, expo-image-picker

I am writing to you in order to get advice about a vexing problem. My React Native Apps tries to open the camera resp. the image library when clicking on a Button, which works perfectly fine on Android, but when trying on ios, the launchCameraAsync and the launchImageLibraryAsync functions will not be executed. I am using expo v49.0.0 for my project, the expo-image-picker v14.3.0 and expo-image-manipulation v11.3.0 libraries to add this functionality.

Here a shortened version of my Code:

```
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, View, Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, Modal, Alert, Pressable } from "react-native";
import { TextInput } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, forwardRef } from "react";
import Services from "../../Service/Services";
import Icon from "../../components/Icon";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import ImageViewer from "../../components/ImageViewer";
import Ionicon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import * as ImageManipulator from 'expo-image-manipulator';
import BasicModal from "../../components/modals/BasicModal";
import colors from "../../config/colors";


function AccountModification({navigation}){


    useEffect(()=>{
        loadProfile();
    }, [navigation]);


    const pickImageAsync = async ()  => {
        if((await ImagePicker.getMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()).status == 'denied' && (await ImagePicker.getMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()).granted == false){

            alert("Bitte gehen sie in Ihre Einstellungen und erlauben sie den Zugriff auf Ihre Galerie!")
        }else{

           await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                allowsEditing:true,
                base64:true,
                quality:0.2,

            }).then(async (response) => {
                console.log("5")

                
                delete response.cancelled;
                
                if (!response.canceled) {
                    let manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(response.assets[0].uri,[{resize:{height:250}}],{base64:true})
                    setSelectedImage(manipResult.base64);
                    ProjectStore.user.image = manipResult.base64;
                    await Services.setProfilePicture(manipResult.base64);
                }
            }).catch(error =>{
                console.log(error)});
        }
    }

    const makePictureAsync = async ()  => {


        if((await ImagePicker.getCameraPermissionsAsync()).status == 'denied' || (await ImagePicker.getCameraPermissionsAsync()).granted == 'false'){

            alert("Bitte gehen sie in Ihre Einstellungen und erlauben sie den Zugriff auf Ihre Kamera!");

        }else if(((await ImagePicker.getCameraPermissionsAsync()).status == 'undetermined')){
            await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
        }else{

            await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
                allowsEditing:true,
                base64:true,
                quality:0.2
            }).then( async (response)=>{

            delete response.cancelled;

            if (!response.canceled) {
                let manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(response.assets[0].uri,[{resize:{height:250}}],{base64:true})
                setSelectedImage(manipResult.base64);
                ProjectStore.user.image = manipResult.base64;
                await Services.setProfilePicture(manipResult.base64);
            }
            }).catch(error => {console.log(error)});
        }   
    }
    

    
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={styles.topContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.profilePictureContainer} onPress={()=>{setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}}>
                    <ImageViewer 
                        placeholderImageSource={PlaceHolder} 
                        selectedImage={selectedImage}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.link}>Profilbild ändern</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                    
                <Text style={styles.userName}>{ProjectStore.userName}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.middleContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.lable}>Vorname</Text>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                value={profileFirstname}
                onChangeText={text => {setProfileFirstname(text);}}
                />
                <Text style={styles.lable}>Nachname</Text>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                value={profileLastname}
                onChangeText={text =>{ setProfileLastname(text);}}
                />
                <Text style={styles.lable}>Email</Text>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                value={profileEmail}
                onChangeText={text =>{ setProfileEmail(text);}}
                />
                <Text style={styles.lable}>Postleitzahl</Text>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                value={profileZipcode}
                onChangeText={text => setProfileZipcode(text)}
                />
                </View>
                    <Modal
                    visible={modalVisible}
                    animationType='slide'
                    transparent={true}
                    >
                    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                        <View style={styles.modal}>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.modalButton} onPress={()=>{setModalVisible(!modalVisible); makePictureAsync()}}>
                                <Ionicon name='camera-outline' size={40}></Ionicon>
                                <Text>Kamera öffnen</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.modalButton} onPress={()=>{setModalVisible(!modalVisible); pickImageAsync()}}>
                                <Ionicon style={styles.icon} size={40} name='images-outline'></Ionicon>
                                <Text>Galerie öffnen</Text>                        
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                        
                    </Modal>
            </View>
        );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    topContainer:{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:"row",
        height:"45%",


    },

    middleContainer:{
        flex:3,
        width:"90%",
        alignSelf:"center",

    },

    profilePictureContainer:{
        marginLeft:10,
        width:Dimensions.get('window').width*0.3,
        height:Dimensions.get('window').width*0.3,
        alignSelf:'center',
        borderRadius:Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width + Dimensions.get('window').height) / 2
    },


    userName:{
        fontSize:20,
        fontWeight:"bold",
        alignSelf: "center",
        marginLeft:"15%",
        borderBottomColor:"black",
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        width:"40%",
        textAlign:"center",
         
    },

    lable:{
        fontSize:12,
        color:"grey",
        backgroundColor:"transparent",
        marginTop:10
    },

    input:{
        fontSize:16,
        borderBottomColor: "lightgrey",
        borderBottomWidth:1,
        padding:5,
        marginTop:-5
    },

    link:{
        color:'dodgerblue',
        paddingTop:4,
        alignSelf:'center'
    },

    centeredView:{
        flex:1,
        marginTop:40,
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'flex-end'

    },

    modal:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent:'space-evenly',
        width:'100%',
        height:"20%",
        backgroundColor:'white',
        alignItems:"center"
    },

    modalButton:{
        alignItems:'center',
    },

    icon:{
   }
})

export default AccountModification;
```

For clarification, permissions have been granted and look like this:

```
{"status":"granted","canAskAgain":true,"expires":"never","granted":true}
```

I tried to ask for permissions again, but await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync() is also not executeable.

I hope someone can help me!

If you need further details please feel free ask.